# Field is given an alias in the SELECT clause, but the query is valid if i use the field name in the ORDER BY clause

Tags: google-bigquery

I give an alias to a field in the SELECT clause, but the query is also valid if i use the field name in the ORDER BY clause:

Select
  word AS word1
from  publicdata:samples.shakespeare s
      where corpus = '1kinghenryiv'
order by word

Is this behaviour intentional or is it a bug?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is intended behavior, and one which is compatible with SQL Standard. ORDER BY can reference columns from the table even if they are not part of SELECT, or as in this case, are renamed in SELECT.
Consider the following two queries (assuming n is an INTEGER)

```
SELECT -n as n1 FROM T ORDER BY n1
```

will produce: ...,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1

```
SELECT -n as n1 FROM T ORDER BY n
```

will produce -1,-2,-3,-4,-5,...

Answer (score 0):

I think, this is a feature that looks more like a bug to me :o)
Please note, if you have alias with the same name it will order by that alias, otherwize it will order by fileld, even if field is not part of the select (but part of data you select from)